# How can I create a python exe file with a sqlite database incorporated?

Tags: python, excel, database, sqlite, exe

I've programed a code in python that uses a sqlite database. Now i need to send an .exe file to other people and they have to run it properly only using the .exe file and without the .db files. But i don't know how to create an executable that includes the sqlite database. Any help?

Comment: Is the database readonly? If yes it can be embedded in the exe (not exactly trivial but at least possible). If not, you can only embed the initial content and save it elsewhere on disk, because an exe file should be seen as readonly.

Comment: Yes is readonly. How can it be embedded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use installers to convert a Python script into a Windows .exe file. Most of them are able to add files to the bundle.

So with PyInstaller, you could:

- at build time:

  - dump the sqlite database (.db file) to a sql script
  - add the script to the PyInstaller bundle in the `data` sub-field of Analysys in the [spec](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/spec-files.html) file
  - convert everything to a single executable
- at run time:

  - the PyInstaller loader will extract the bundle into a temporary folder
  - the python code can get the path of that folder in [`sys._MEIPASS`](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/runtime-information.html)
  - from there on, it knows the path of the dump and can load it into a in-memory database:

    ```
      import sqlite3
      ...
      con = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
      con.executescript(open(path_to_dump_file).read())
    ```
  - `con` now gives access to the content of the database...

This only gives hints on the how-to, but a detailed recipe would really depend on the installer and on your applicaiton.